# Extra Spaces Being Added After Clear Screen

Tags: c, ansi-escape

I have the following code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define RESET "\x1b[1J"

#define D "\x1b[0m"
#define Y "\x1b[33;1m"
#define W "\x1b[37;1m"
#define B "\x1b[30;1m"

void printLeft(bool color)
{
  if (color) {
    printf(Y "               __\n"
           "              /  |\n"
           "             /   \\\n"
           "            /     |\n"
           W "      _\\|  " Y "|" W "[" B "*" W "][" B "*" W "]" Y "|  " W "|/_\n"
           "        \\  " Y "|      |  " W "/\n"
           "         --" Y "|" W "\\____/" Y "|" W "--\n"
           Y "           \\      |\n"
           "            \\     /\n"
           "             \\   |\n"
           W "             |" Y "\\__|" W "|\n"
           "             |    |\n"
           "           ==|    |==");
  } else {
    printf("               __\n"
           "              /  |\n"
           "             /   \\\n"
           "            /     |\n"
           "      _\\|  |[*][*]|  |/_\n"
           "        \\  |      |  /\n"
           "         --|\\____/|--\n"
           "           \\      |\n"
           "            \\     /\n"
           "             \\   |\n"
           "             |\\__||\n"
           "             |    |\n"
           "           ==|    |==");
  }
}

void printRight(bool color) {
  if (color) {
    printf(Y "               __\n"
           "              |  \\\n"
           "              /   \\\n"
           "             |     \\\n"
           W "        _\\|  " Y "|" W "[" B "*" W "][" B "*" W "]" Y "|  " W "|/_\n"
           "          \\  " Y "|      |  " W "/\n"
           "           --" Y "|" W "\\____/" Y "|" W "--\n"
           Y "             |      /\n"
           "             \\     /\n"
           "              |   /\n"
           W "             |" Y "|__/" W "|\n"
           "             |    |\n"
           "           ==|    |==");
  } else {
    printf("               __\n"
           "              |  \\\n"
           "              /   \\\n"
           "             |     \\\n"
           "        _\\|  |[*][*]|  |/_\n"
           "          \\  |      |  /\n"
           "           --|\\____/|--\n"
           "             |      /\n"
           "             \\     /\n"
           "              |   /\n"
           "             ||__/|\n"
           "             |    |\n"
           "           ==|    |==");
  }
}

void printBottom(bool color) {
  if (color) {
    printf(Y "               __\n"
           "              |  |\n"
           "             /    \\\n"
           "            |      |\n"
           "            |" W "[" B "*" W "][" B "*" W "]" Y"|\n"
           "            |      |\n"
           W "        _\\| " Y "|" W "\\____/" Y "| " W "|/_\n"
           "          \\/" Y "|      |" W "\\/\n"
           Y "            |      |\n"
           W "           /\\" Y "\\    /" W "/\\\n"
           "        ==/   " Y "|__|   " W "\\==");
  } else {
    printf("               __\n"
           "              |  |\n"
           "             /    \\\n"
           "            |      |\n"
           "            |[*][*]|\n"
           "            |      |\n"
           "        _\\| |\\____/| |/_\n"
           "          \\/|      |\\/\n"
           "            |      |\n"
           "           /\\\\    //\\\n"
           "        ==/   |__|   \\==");
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  short counter = 0;
  while (1) {
    printf(RESET);
    if (counter == 0) printLeft(true);
    else if (counter == 2) printRight(true);
    else printBottom(true);
    if (true) {
      printf(Y "\n\n\"IT'S PEANUT BUTTER JELLY TIME\"" D);
    } else {
      printf("\n\n\"IT'S PEANUT BUTTER JELLY TIME\"");
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    usleep(200000);
    counter = (counter + 1) % 4;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Everything works wonderfully, except for one thing. There appears to be extra space added on the first line:

[image: extra space]

How can I get rid of this extra space?

Comment: Is it because of the faulty logic here: `if (true) {...} else {...}` which causes the first output text to always be output?

Comment: @WeatherVane For each method yes the color version will be output. I will add a flag to switch to color or not color later.

Comment: the posted code is missing  #include statements for stdio.h and unistd.h and stdbool.h    There is no definition of `RESET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't test with the control codes on my system, you most likely need a `\n` after this text:

```
printf(Y "\n\n\"IT'S PEANUT BUTTER JELLY TIME\"\n" D);
```

At least, this fixes the same problem here on a Windows system (and `Y` and `D` seem to be color control codes, so this shouldn't affect the position anyway).

**Update**:

Seems like a [position control code](http://asf.atmel.com/docs/latest/avr32.drivers.macb.example.evk1100/html/group__group__avr32__utils__print__funcs.html) exists too (can't test it here though):

```
#define     GOTOYX   "\x1B[%.2d;%.2dH"
    Set cursor to (y, x). More...
```

So you could possibly use this code to position your first line instead of that extra newline.

Comment: That does work but it does put an extra newline on the bottom which I guess isn't the end of the world. Thank!

Comment: Maybe you could do a check when to add a newline and when not? But don't you have controlcodes available for position also? That might even be better.

Comment: Yes. I think I have figured it out. Maybe `\x1b[1J` retains the cursor position (I thought it would reset it). I will find a control code to fix that. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting a `\n` character before the first line.

Comment: It slowly moves down the screen but afterwards this does work.

Answer (score 0):

I;m on ubuntu linux 14.04 compiling with gcc.

The following code cleanly compiles and perform the desired operation.

I was not able to get the `\1b[2j`  (clear screen) to work, and found that I did not need it.

Some of the significant changes were

1. end the last line of each graphic with `\n` so last line always immediately output
2. modified the graphics to all be the same width and height
3. modified the `if(true)` statement to alternate between the coloured and plain text output
4. removed the unnecessary call to `fflush()`
5. the reason for the bad offset for the first line of the graphic was  not using correct spacing to allow for the `w` at the beginning of a line in the graphic and not outputting the whole graphic output and not making all the graphics the same height/width.

The following code is the result

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define D "\x1b[0m"
#define Y "\x1b[33;1m"
#define W "\x1b[37;1m"
#define B "\x1b[30;1m"
#define CURSOR_1_1 "\x1b[1;1f \n"

void printLeft(bool color)
{
  if (color) {
    printf(CURSOR_1_1
           Y
           "               __                               \n"
           "              /  |                              \n"
           "             /   \\                             \n"
           "            /     |                             \n"
           W
           "      _\\|  " Y "|" W "[" B "*" W "][" B "*" W "]" Y "|  " W "|/_\n"
           "        \\  " Y "|      |  " W "/               \n"
           "         --" Y "|" W "\\____/" Y "|" W "--      \n"
           Y
           "           \\      |                            \n"
           "            \\     /                            \n"
           "             \\   |                             \n"
           W
           "             |" Y "\\__|" W "|                  \n"
           "             |    |                             \n"
           "           ==|    |=                            \n");
  } else {
    printf(CURSOR_1_1
           "               __                               \n"
           "              /  |                              \n"
           "             /   \\                             \n"
           "            /     |                             \n"
           "      _\\|  |[*][*]|  |/_                       \n"
           "        \\  |      |  /                         \n"
           "         --|\\____/|--                          \n"
           "           \\      |                            \n"
           "            \\     /                            \n"
           "             \\   |                             \n"
           "             |\\__||                            \n"
           "             |    |                             \n"
           "           ==|    |==                           \n");
  }
}

void printRight(bool color) {
  if (color) {
    printf(CURSOR_1_1
           Y
           "               __                               \n"
           "              |  \\                             \n"
           "              /   \\                            \n"
           "             |     \\                           \n"
           W
           "        _\\|  " Y "|" W "[" B "*" W "][" B "*" W "]" Y "|  " W "|/_        \n"
           "          \\  " Y "|      |  " W "/             \n"
           "           --" Y "|" W "\\____/" Y "|" W "--    \n"
           Y
           "             |      /                           \n"
           "             \\     /                           \n"
           "              |   /                             \n"
           W
           "             |" Y "|__/" W "|                   \n"
           "             |    |                             \n"
           "           ==|    |==                           \n");
  } else {
    printf(CURSOR_1_1
           "               __                               \n"
           "              |  \\                             \n"
           "              /   \\                            \n"
           "             |     \\                           \n"
           "        _\\|  |[*][*]|  |/_                     \n"
           "          \\  |      |  /                       \n"
           "           --|\\____/|--                        \n"
           "             |      /                           \n"
           "             \\     /                           \n"
           "              |   /                             \n"
           "             ||__/|                             \n"
           "             |    |                             \n"
           "           ==|    |==                           \n");
  }
}

void printBottom(bool color) {
  if (color) {
    printf(CURSOR_1_1
           Y
           "               __                               \n"
           "              |  |                              \n"
           "             /    \\                            \n"
           "            |      |                            \n"
           "            |" W "[" B "*" W "][" B "*" W "]" Y"|         \n"
           "            |      |                            \n"
           W
           "        _\\| " Y "|" W "\\____/" Y "| " W "|/_  \n"
           "          \\/" Y "|      |" W "\\/              \n"
           Y
           "            |      |                            \n"
           W
           "           /\\" Y "\\    /" W "/\\              \n"
           "        ==/   " Y "|__|   " W "\\==             \n"
           "                                                \n"
           "                                                \n");
  } else {
    printf(CURSOR_1_1
           "               __                               \n"
           "              |  |                              \n"
           "             /    \\                            \n"
           "            |      |                            \n"
           "            |[*][*]|                            \n"
           "            |      |                            \n"
           "        _\\| |\\____/| |/_                      \n"
           "          \\/|      |\\/                        \n"
           "            |      |                            \n"
           "           /\\\\    //\\                        \n"
           "        ==/   |__|   \\==                       \n"
           "                                                \n"
           "                                                \n");
  }
}

int main( void )
{
    int counter = 0;
    printf(CURSOR_1_1);
    while (1)
    {
        if (counter == 0) printLeft(true);
        else if (counter == 2) printRight(true);
        else printBottom(true);

        if (counter&0x01)
        {
          printf(Y "\n\n\"IT'S PEANUT BUTTER JELLY TIME\"%s\n", D );
        }

        else
        {
          printf("\n\n\"IT'S PEANUT BUTTER JELLY TIME\"\n");
        }
        //fflush(stdout);
        usleep(200000);
        counter = (counter + 1) % 4;
    }
    return 0;
}
```